# Can I get a string representation of a condition passed as a bool into a function?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I know the title is probably really hard to understand, it was hard to think of a proper title, but here's the essence of what I want to do.

Basically I want to have a method like this:

```
void Validate(bool validation)
{
    if (!validation)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

And then I want to call it like:

```
try
{
    Validate(1 > 2);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // This is where I would output the error to the user
}
```

I want to get the `1 > 2` part as a string without defining it as one elsewhere, or evaluating a string to a `bool`, or using predicates, or using external methods. Ideally this would be done via reflection. I'll also take suggestions on a better way to do what I want to do. Assume that the `bool` could be anything: `1 > 2`, `"cheese" != "ham"`, `objectA == objectB`, etc.

Comment: Can you give more context? Where is this used and how? Validation is very common, it seems like you should be able to take advantage of existing solutions out there.

Comment: I'm looking to make a pre-processor of sorts for a project I'm working on. I'm basically going to build a fully functional C# class that will be compiled via the CS-Script project (http://www.csscript.net/), I'm doing this because I want to dumb down C# a bit for non-programmer development. One of the pre-defined methods will be a Validate() method that will allow the scripter to perform comparisons, and if it fails (or succeeds even) I want it to show what failed/succeeded on the screen during the script execution.

Comment: Also as a side note, since I know I can just read the "script" and pull the comparison out manually, I'd like to avoid that and perform the operation post-compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Well, perhaps you happen to can (in Python, one could hack something like this together, I suppose, although it wouldn't be pretty, wouldn't work reliably and would require having the source code at hand), but generally:

- You don't have string repesentations of code at runtime.
- Arguments (expressions) are evaluated before the function is called.
- The evaluation yields nothing but a lone bool that doesn't remember the slightest bit about where it came from.

Before you're looking for some nasty nasty hack to emulate this, check if it isn't easier to add a string literal during compilation.

Comment: Choosing yours because the more I look at it, the more I think how horrible of an idea this is. I'm also realizing i'm going to need to be doing a lot more of data extraction than will make this easy. For example, I need to do something like Validate(PowerSupply.Current > 0.055); where powersupply is a representation of a real life power supply, and have it display what the current is, and what it's comparing to. I'm going to take your suggestion and look for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you are going to be able to get is to use lambda expressions, which would look something to the effect of:

```
void Validate(Expression<Func<bool>> validation)
{
    if (!Lambda.Compile(validation)())
    {
        string message = "..." //parse lambda expression here.
        //see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

        throw new Exception(message);
    }
}


try
{
   Validate(() => 1 > 2);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write(e.Message)// This is where I would output the error to the user
}
```

Though, honestly, I'm not sure it's worth the trouble, and you wouldn't want to use it in a tight loop, due to the dynamic compilation of the lambda expression (though you could possibly cache the result of the compilation if necessary)